# Kinect Handtracking in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, kinect

I'm trying to create an application using the Kinect to simulate the following project:

[Kinect Hand Tracking](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNzX_0cSaS8&feature=player_embedded)

I want my project to have similar usability with the Kinect tracking hand and finger positions for use in a menu system, or to navigate another system.

What I would like to know is; is it possible for the exact same to be accomplished in XNA using Kinect?

I know that it can be done in Winform / C#, but I know XNA / C# a lot better and would (ideally) prefer to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's a very sophisticated Library to handle finger tracking, shouldn't be too hard to port to XNA 
http://candescentnui.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/20148